# How to iterate through Groups (GroupBy) in Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas

I got a code that comes from a previous Python version (at least I think so) that  doesn't seem to work on Python 3. How can I overcome this?

**Here is the data set for testing:**

```
import pandas as pd

ipl_data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(ipl_data)
```

**Here is the problematic code :**

```
grouped = df.groupby('Year')

for name,group in grouped:
   print name
   print group
```

**I'm supposed to obtain this :**

```
2014
   Points  Rank     Team   Year
0     876     1   Riders   2014
2     863     2   Devils   2014
4     741     3   Kings    2014
9     701     4   Royals   2014

2015
   Points  Rank     Team   Year
1     789     2   Riders   2015
3     673     3   Devils   2015
5     812     4    kings   2015
10    804     1   Royals   2015

2016
   Points  Rank     Team   Year
6     756     1    Kings   2016
8     694     2   Riders   2016

2017
   Points  Rank    Team   Year
7     788     1   Kings   2017
11    690     2  Riders   2017
```

**But when I launched the code I got this error message :**

```
Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(name)?
```

**So I changed the code to this :**

```
for name,group in grouped:
   print(name)
   print(group)
```

**I launched the code I got this error message:**

> cannot unpack non-iterable int object

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Run `grouped = df.groupby('Year')` again before your update

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not wrong, it gives exactly the result which you require.

You probably worked interactively in Python Console or in Jupyter Notebook. Your error message

> cannot unpack non-iterable int object

(related to the command `for name, group in grouped:`) suggests that between changing Python 2 `print` commands to Python 3 `print()` functions and rerunning the `for` loop again, you assigned an integer value to the `grouped` variable.